# Idiom for dabbling in extremes

Tags: expression-choice, idiom-requests

Is there a suitable idiomatic expression for a situation in which a person tends to dabble in extremes? For example, he might wake up at 4:00AM on some days and wake up at 11:00 AM on others and so on...

Comment: There is always the obvious corollary to Ben Franklin's: "*Early to bed, early to rise, makes a man healthy, wealthy and wise.*"  So your guy is gonna be one poor sick idiot. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Man of extremes* is a common idiomatic expression.